# What utilities do you use and how do you use them when benchmarking your harddrive subsystem for a SAN replacement?

Tags: performance, storage-area-network, iscsi, benchmark, monitoring

So, I have a series of questions into ServerFault about LeftHand SAN's (Questions [1441](https://serverfault.com/questions/1441/does-anyone-have-experience-with-lefthands-vsa-san) and [4478](https://serverfault.com/questions/4478/how-does-the-lefthand-san-perform-in-a-production-environment)).  One of the [responses](https://serverfault.com/questions/4478/how-does-the-lefthand-san-perform-in-a-production-environment/4626#4626) I received questioned the throughput of the iSCSI data returning from the SAN being restricted to the 1GB network card.

I think it is a very good point to look at.

Now to see if this would be an actual bottleneck for my purpose I should perform some benchmarks on the current production server.

What utilities should I use for profiling?
If there are special metrics I should be reading, what are they?  IOPS?, Disk Read/Write B/sec?, etc...

Thank you,

Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Iometer](http://www.iometer.org/) appears to be the overwhelming recommendation for testing and benchmarking iSCSI SAN performance. Because it is widely used by vendors, its numbers offer a fairly reliable comparison metric across storage systems.

If you plan on running SQL Server off your SAN, you should also look at doing some testing and tuning with [SQLIO](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9a8b005b-84e4-4f24-8d65-cb53442d9e19&displaylang=en). Brent Ozar has a great S[AN performance tuning guide](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SAN_Performance_Tuning_with_SQLIO) at SQLServerPedia using the SQLIO tool that's worth checking out.

Comment: I use SQLIO with a suite of 16 tests: [read/write]/[sequential/random]/[8/64/128/256kB IOs].

Answer (score 1):

[IOMeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iometer) is the tool I normally use for this type of thing...

Comment: Does IOMeter come with a command line version, the screenshots suggest it is a GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

[Bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/) is a nice unix benchmarking tool for hard disks.  It'll complete a wide variety of tests.